# Is there an hack that could allow me to print with only Cyan using my RGB printer?

Tags: photoshop, printing, color-management, printer

I have no CYMK printers but i do have RGB ones, in addition I have a ColorMunki Photo for calibration.

I'm experimenting some Cyanographic photo processing, for my purposes that is what I want to achieve.

**I would like to do the same of when you select into the printer driver: Print only with black ink. But with the Cyan ink.**

I'm not interested in the final density or the cyan color printed, I just want to have paper printed with my actual cyan ink without any addition of magenta and yellow into the mixture.

I know that in photoshop my process would be convert to CMYK then do a black and white mix and add a screen layer with pure cyan on top, but the problem is having only the cyan ink being printed.

Can you suggest me a way to do this without do hardware modifications to the printer like pour cyan ink inside a cleaned empty black cartridge or swap the MYK cartridges with dried up ones?

There are raw drivers that allows me to bypass the current canon processing drivers? Or maybe with the munki I can find the perfect hue so that after the color processing will be printed by the driver with just the Cyan ink excluding magenta and yellows addon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be purely about printing rather than about photography. If this is for a photographic reason, please edit the question to explain the relevance to photography.

Comment: @user3450548: [here are the instructions, in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32831298#32831298).

Comment: @EuriPinhollow - Please do not use comments to provide answers and instructions. If you want to answer the question, please use the answer fields instead.

Comment: JoanneC: I will make an answer if it is good way of doing the task.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways of doing it in Photoshop:

- using CMYK mode of printer
- using RGB mode of printer

Either can be unsupported depending on the model.

Using CMYK:

- convert to BW using any method you'd like (desaturation is the simpliest);
- switch the mode from RGB to CMYK (`Image->Mode`), use any suggested profile;
- use channel mixer with following values respectably: {0, 0, 0, 100; 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0} (the only positive value is 100 for "Black" in "Cyan" output channel)
- disable colour management and all adjustments in your printer settings completely (this may be tricky, one should pick the settings which are used for profiling)
- pick "Printer manages colours" in Photoshop
- print

The choise of CMYK profile will affect tonality. Pick different CMYK profile or adjust it with curves for liking.

Using RGB:

- invert
- use channel mixer with following values: {33, 33, 33; 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0} (red output channel has equal amount of every input channel)
- invert
- disable colour management and all adjustments in your printer settings completely (this may be tricky, one should pick the settings which are used for profiling)
- pick "Printer manages colours" in Photoshop
- print

The result will depend on the gamma of RGB colour space which is in use. Again, pick one which is better.

It is likely that you will get pure inks in either way but it is not guaranteed. 
These actions can be scripted.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a [RIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_image_processor) software for your printer that allows that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting the file to B/W and switching the cartridges of black and cyan ink (that is, if your printer has separate cartridges for each color)?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//photo.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).